# How to gather all chats a Telegram bot is an admin of?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, iterable

How is it possible to get all chats in the form of a iterabale object (list-like) or iterate over all possible chats the bot is an admin/participant of (using `python-telegram-bot`)? Is there a `python-telegram-bot` `method` for getting all chats a bot is a admin/participant of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not, because the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) does not provide such a method. You can use the [`Update.my_chat_member`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a6/telegram.update.html#telegram.Update.my_chat_member) updates to keep track of that. See [here](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a6/examples.html#examples-chatmemberbot) for an example on how that can be done using `python-telgeram-bot`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.